# Display in GraphQL values from multiple products

Tags: magento2, graphql, magento-graphql

I am trying to load in graphql product details.
I am only managing to get the details of one product $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'][0] but I would like to get the values for all the products which are in $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'].
In resolver I have:

```
return [
        'cart' => [
            'products' => [
                'sku' => $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'][0]['ItemCode'],
                'quantity' => $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'][0]['ItemQuantity'],
                'price' => $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'][0]['ItemQuantity']
            ],
]
```

in schema.graphqls I have:

```
type AddProductsToCartOutput {
products: ITEMS
}


type ITEMS {
sku: String!
quantity: Float!
price: Float!
}
```

in the request:

```
   cart {
  
products {
    sku
    quantity
    price
}
}
```

and in the output I am getting:

```
"cart": {
    "products": {
      "sku": "33150220000",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 5
    },
 }
```

But I need to show all the items!

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass multiple items data to graphql output you will have to define the ITEMS as array in your schema.graphqls

Try changing with below code

```
type AddProductsToCartOutput {
    products: [ITEMS]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: thank you but how do i show afterwards all the products? 'sku' =>?

Comment: You will have to loop through the data you are having in the resolver and pass all the products data array in the resolver. Above query will return array of products objects.

Comment: in my resolver i have return [
        'cart' => [
            'products' => [
                'sku' => $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'][0]['ItemCode'],
                'quantity' => $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'][0]['ItemQuantity'],
                'price' => $json['Transaction']['OrderItems'][0]['ItemQuantity']
            ],
] what should i change there? could you help me?